# migrating sql query controller symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, controller, symfony4

hello I'm migrating from `symfony 2.5` to `4.1` and I find myself with a mishap in the controller, before `mibundle:miaccion` now how can I do?

```
$repositoryEstado = $em->getRepository('MiBundle:miaction');        
$queryEstado = $repositoryEstado->createQueryBuilder('alias')
                                ->where('alias.id = :id')
                                ->setParameter('id', $idEstado)
                                ->andWhere('alias.estado = :estado')
                                ->setParameter('estado', true)
                                ->getQuery();
$resultEstado = $queryEstado->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Comment: what's your problem ?

Comment: I'm not using bundle as I do this query without the bundle, because I'm migrating it from symfony 2. to symfony 4

Comment: which bundle???

Comment: Exactly, before the bundle was created, now it is not used. How do I apply this sql query that calls a bundle that does not exist?.
I hope you can give me to understand, I'm sorry English is not my language

Comment: this does not call any bundle but call `miaction` Repository that is actually an entity.If this entity belong to a bundle install it , else you can't do anything.

Comment: So I just call the entity to make the query?

Comment: is `MiBunlde` a vendor or your custom bundle?

Comment: this query is in my symfony 2.5 the bundle generates them with console, everything as it was done in that then I already create my entities, now I want to create the queries of my controller 2.5 to 4.1, I just want to customize the controllers, nothing is external

Comment: SO where is the problem, this is a doctrine query that does not change in Symfony 4 because it's **Doctrine 2**.

Comment: if there is a problem, why "mibundle" does not exist anymore
and I already remove that fraction and no, I get an error in query

Comment: Symfony 4 is **Bundleless** but you can still use them like before. **BUT** it s not the best practice !

Comment: Right, I'm not using it. the query is about the way to do the action in the controller without using the bundle, remove the bundle and just call the entity and I get a query error.
would you be so kind to leave me an example of a "select from join" as it is currently done in symfony4 and I accommodate all others

Comment: Symfony doesn t do any query , that's **ORM**  (usually **Doctrine2**)

Comment: it's ok I'll read more about ORM thanks

Comment: If you don't want to use ORM you ve to create your own class that manage [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

Comment: Okay, I have a couple of months left to migrate